# What electrical wires are ok for 90C flushmount lighs?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I got a flushmount ceiling light that has a 90C wiring warning on it.

My home was built in 1956. I found the electrical wiring that runs to the light I want to change. I can't read the text printed on the wiring completely, it partially reads:

```
TYPE NM-B 600 VOLT9
```

Here's a picture of the fixture on the other side:

[image]

Anyone know if "NM-B" wiring is safe for 90C?

Thanks

Comment: In this day and age there is no earthly reason for a new residential luminaire to rise to 90C.  That much heat is only made by incandescents (quite obsolete) or high-intensity discharge lights (decently efficient, but far too bright for residential, and obsolete too).

Answer (score 3):

NM-B is rated for 90°C.  Here's an excerpt from [Southwire’s Romex® SIMpull® Type NM-B](http://www.southwire.com/products/RomexSIMpullTypeNMBOEM.htm) web page.

> Southwire’s Romex® SIMpull® Type NM-B (non-metallic sheathed cable) may be used for both exposed and concealed work in normally dry locations at temperatures not to exceed 90°C...

From NEC

> ## National Electrical Code 2017
>
> ### Chapter 3 Wiring Methods and Materials
>
> #### Article 334 Nonmetallic-Sheathed Cable: Types NM, NMC, and NMS
>
> **334.112 Insulation.** ...Conductor insulation shall be rated at 90°C (194°F).

However, keep in mind that the ampacity is limited to that of a 60°C conductor.